# Python: How to print lines from a file after receiving user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Bear with i am new to programming. I am trying to create a program that will print a **specific** chunk of lines from a file, wait for a users input and then print another **specific** chunk etc. Essentially, a program that prints lines [1, 2 and 3], asks the user for their input and then prints lines [4, 5 and 6] etc.

**By specific i only mean certain lines from the external text file**

I have no idea how to do this essentially, and am only really able to print specific lines from a file.

```
lines = []
for line in enumerate(open("mathsquiz.txt" , "r")):
    lines.append(line)
    targetlines = [4, 5, 10, 11, 16, 17, 22, 23]
    for line in lines:
        if line[0] not in targetlines:
            print(line[1])
```

Comment: Please do not edit your question (and the other questions) to remove all the content, the idea is the question might be useful for future users. If you want your username dissociated from the post then flag it to the moderators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but try:

```
targetlines = [4, 5, 10, 11, 16, 17, 22, 23]
with open("mathsquiz.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for n, line in enumerate(f_in):
       if n in targetlines:
           print(line)
```

Again, not tested but should work:

```
while True:     
    s=input('enter lines separated by spaces:')     
    if s.strip()=='': break
    tgt=[int(e) for e in s.split()]
    print(tgt)
    with open("mathsquiz.txt", "r") as f_in:
        for n, line in enumerate(f_in):
            if n in tgt:
               print(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: Just wrap another loop around this that asks for the input. Try it.